# SLF4J bindings error

Tags: slf4j, mahout

I'm a newbie at mahout and I'm struggling to install it on my ubuntu 12.10. As I've seen many problems relating to SLF4J and Eclipse, I mention that I don't use Eclipse.

The maven compilation works fine. (mvn install -DskipTests=true)

I think I have properly set my environment variables, here is my /etc/environment :

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/
MAHOUT_HOME=/home/edelans/mahout/
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/conf
```

I started getting some errors when I started to try and run some example scripts:

```
root@edelans-ubuntu-master:/home/edelans/mahout/examples/bin# ./cluster-reuters.sh 
Please select a number to choose the corresponding clustering algorithm
1. kmeans clustering
2. fuzzykmeans clustering
3. dirichlet clustering
4. minhash clustering
Enter your choice : 1
ok. You chose 1 and we'll use kmeans Clustering
creating work directory at /tmp/mahout-work-root
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, so we don't add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, running locally
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/edelans/mahout/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/edelans/mahout/examples/target/dependency/slf4j-jcl-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/edelans/mahout/examples/target/dependency/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.<clinit>(MahoutDriver.java:89)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver. Program will exit.
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /home/edelans/mahout/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar
12/11/21 14:48:23 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Maximum n-gram size is: 1
12/11/21 14:48:23 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Minimum LLR value: 1.0
12/11/21 14:48:23 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Number of reduce tasks: 1
12/11/21 14:48:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:54310/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/root/.staging/job_201211211039_0002
12/11/21 14:48:24 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/mahout-work-root/reuters-out-seqdir
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/mahout-work-root/reuters-out-seqdir
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocuments(DocumentProcessor.java:93)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.run(SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.main(SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Another user had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773694/playframework-multiple-slf4j-bindings?answertab=votes#tab-top) but I didn't know how to write the line of code that answered his problem:

```
"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-core" % "0.7" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))
```

And I don't have the authorization to comment his question... Sorry to open another question for that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PlayFramework Multiple SLF4J bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773694/playframework-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is described right there in the stack trace. You are mixing in a much older version of slf4j in your project. Don't do that. If it's coming from a third party you need to exclude it from being brought in.

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/edelans/mahout/examples/target/dependency/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. How can I exclude this version of slf4j ? As I stated at the end of my question, I don't get the answer of [PlayFramework Multiple SLF4J bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773694/playframework-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

Comment: I don't know, how have you included it?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't do it on purpose =). Where can I see where it comes from ? I didn't modify the pom.xml.
Should I delete slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar from `/home/edelans/mahout/examples/target/dependency/` ? Or modify the pom.xml ?